# Bring div to front on fixed position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I used `fixed` `position` for a `div` in a webpage to stick the `div` as a a header on the top, but on scrolling it comes behind all other objects like `divs`, videos and even text!

Here is the `div` as it should look at all times:
[image: div as it should look at all times]

How the `div` hides when it is scrolled down:
[image: div hides when it is scrolled down]

So, I just thought of the basic structure that if I write that particular `div`'s code in the starting (which I did) and then other objects', the other objects will naturally come in front. So, one solution could be to write its code at the end. But, I have a structural code with proper placed comments in between and this could spoil it.

This is the code:

```
<div style="width: 1409.25px; height:40px; top:0; left:0; position:fixed; background-color:black; line-height:2;">..Text here..</div>
```

Is there any way to bring the `div` in front when scrolling without writing its code at the end?

Comment: have you tried z-index?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add a `z-index`, this will put the divs into z space based on the `z-index` value,

Example:

```
<div id="a" style="z-index:10"></div>
<div id="b" style="z-index:1"></div>
```

Div a will be placed above Div b as it has a higher `z-index`.

Here is a simple JSFiddle example - https://jsfiddle.net/ta2gbn4m/

Comment: z-index did work. I thought I would have to put it to all of the divs as you mentioned index 10. But putting on only one worked. Rest divs I don't need to adjust as only one was overlapping the other.

Comment: @Error404 what adarsh is saying, is if you put the nav inside of a header tag and set the z-index of the header it will put everything with-in the tag to that z-index, instead of setting a z-index of every div, and it will automatically set the content to be behind saying you time on editing the contents z-index individually

Answer (score 2):

For your header set the z-index value something higher then the below div wrapper

example

```
 header{
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  z-index:9999
}
div{
position:relative;
z-index:2 // lesser then the header z-index value
}
```

higher the z-index it comes on top of other element which had lower z-index value